# How to keep version locked on Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.win-x64 in .Net 6 API

Tags: nuget, .net-6.0

We have an .Net 6 API.

We have our own Nuget server to ensure we have backup of used Nuget packages so we always are sure we can run our CI chain.

After the upgrade to .Net 6, then every time MS publishes a new version of any of these three assemblies then our CI builds fail, because our NuGet server doesn't have the new version.

- Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.win-x64
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Runtime.win-x64
- Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.Runtime.win-x64

Latest with 6.0.8. We then have to download the new packages to our Nuget server and then everything works.

In general I would like us to keep on known versions all the time, and only change referenced package version on purpose - and not just because developers publish new versions.

But I can't find any explicit references to these three packages.

Does anyone know where they come from - and more importantly - are there any way to lock our solution to use e.g. 6.0.8, until we decide to upgrade next time?

Best regards

/Anders